# HTML5 jquery mobile geolocation content

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I'm new to HTML5 geolocation. I want to display content based on the geolocation using either html5 or jquery mobile. Can someone give me suggestions or example on how to approach the same.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery mobile example: 
http://codingisfun.com/archives/128

HTML5 example: 
http://html5demos.com/geo Basically this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}
```